# Why do I still have a record of (non-existent) delete and undelete votes?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, voting

If we close questions rather than delete them, why does my user profile still include an overview of all 0 delete and undelete votes I've cast?

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/5498/vincent?tab=votes&sort=deletion (I know this link won't work for regular users, but maybe it does for mods.)

[image: no deletion votes cast]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With sufficient rep you'll have more comprehensive delete vote abilities. The relevant privilege levels are "[Access To Moderator Tools](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)" for questions and "[Trusted User](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)" for answers. More info on the mechanics can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/216955), but this is the relevant bit:

> #### How a post can be deleted by a user:
>
> 3. **Users with reputation >= 10k** (more precisely, the “moderator tools”
>    privilege;
>    2k on beta sites) can vote to delete *questions* that have been
>    closed/on-hold for 48 hours. It takes three votes to delete;
>    more if the question is popular, but ten votes at most.
> 4. **Users with reputation >= 20k** (more precisely, the “trusted user”
>    privilege; 4k
>    on beta sites) are not subject to the 48-hour waiting period for
>    deleting closed questions with a score of -3 or lower. They may also
>    delete *answers* of score -1 or lower. It takes three votes to delete
>    an answer.
> 5. **Six users with reputation >= 2k** (more precisely, the “Edit Questions And Answers”
>    privilege; 1k on
>    beta sites) [can cause automatic deletion of a post if they choose
>    "recommend deletion" from within the low quality review
>    queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145292/152859).

It's not easy for me to determine if a "recommend deletion" vote does not show up in you deletion votes tab or if you've just never recommended deletion on a post. Since you're an avid reviewer, I'd assume the former.

Comment: Ah, that explains. I was afraid this was some legacy functionality. Thanks!

Comment: @Vincent hurry up and get to 20k rep, it makes the mods' jobs easier and I need a vacation! ;)

Comment: We don't even have 20k *combined*, my friend. Start upvoting those answers, I'd say! :P